# Always see last-viewed group in Contacts

Tags: contacts

Whenever I view **Contacts** it always defaults to the full list.

Is there a way to make it show the last-viewed Group of contacts? Or at the very least a specific group?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't know of this is possible but it will likely depend on the phone model you have because most manufacturers put their own spin on how contacts are handled.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, I was afraid of that.

Comment: I was implying that you should list the details of your device  so you can get a more relevant answer.

Comment: it's not a solution for contacts, so i'll post it here instead of answering, but [TouchPal Dialer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cootek.smartdialer&hl=en) displays favorites easily, and automatically shows the people you contact most frequently.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using google contacts as your address book, you could star those people you always want to come up, and then use the star folder on your desktop making it a quick easy way to always have access to them.

The Folder Organizer app will also allow you do this and isn't limited to using just the google address boo, and it also has more features enabling you to pick specific details from a contact i.e. choose only mobile instead of all their details etc.

I know it doesn't answer your question specifically in terms of the contact app, but it does provide a decent work around. Note that depending on your phone it might have built in widgets that can aid i.e. Sense has a pretty good one for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

In order to do that on Gingerbread select 'Display options' from the menu of the Contacts app. Then under 'Choose contacts to display' select your account and check only the groups you are interested in.

[image]

Comment: That's not really answering his question, is it? I don't think he's looking to restrict the number of contacts on his phone, but rather preserve his last view.

Comment: It doesn't restrict the number of contacts on the phone, it just defines which contacts to display. Moreover, this answers the following part of the question: "Or at the very least a specific group?" Finally, if you have a better answer, feel free to post it.

Comment: I don't, but I am interested in the solution.

Comment: Thanks **Adam** :) Sorry I wasn't more clear. While your solution does display a specific group I think doing this might prevent the Caller ID from displaying the contacts in the non-selected groups? Also, I forgot to specify that I'm still stuck on Froyo.